# Setting both platform and python version in install requires

Tags: python, setup.py

I have a setup.py file and I would like to specify both the platform and the python version for installation requirements in setup.py but this setup does not work

Here is what I have tried

```
install_requires=['pyproj>1.9.5.1;platform_system!="Windows";python_version>"3.4"']
```

I am unable to do

```
setup.py sdist bdist_wheel --universal
```

It doesn't recognize two environment markers in the same line

Any thoughts or suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `and`, `or`, and parenthesis `(` `)` to combine markers:

```
install_requires=['pyproj>1.9.5.1 ; platform_system != "Windows" and python_version > "3.4"']
```