# How to specify platforms-specific extras or version in Pipfile?

Tags: python, pip, pipenv, pipenv-install

The ["Advanced Usage of Pipenv" docs](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/advanced/#specifying-basically-anything), in the "Specifying Basically Anything" section, explains how to include a package requirement, conditionally on the os platform, in the `Pipfile`, eg:

```
pywinusb = {version = "*", sys_platform = "== 'win32'"}
```

It's not clear what to do when one wants to specify different version or options for a package, depending on the platform.

Specifically, I have this requirement:

```
faust = {version=">=1.10.1", extras=["aiodns", "ciso8601", "cython"]}
```

and I want to exclude the optional extra `ciso8601` in Windows.

If I write

```
faust = {version=">=1.10.1", extras=["aiodns", "ciso8601", "cython"], platform_system = "!= 'Windows'"}
faust = {version=">=1.10.1", extras=["aiodns", "cython"], platform_system = "== 'Windows'"}
```

I get the error: `tomlkit.exceptions.KeyAlreadyPresent: Key "faust " already exists.`

Additionally, I want the same thing in the `setup.py` (`install_requires` section).

Comment: `install_requires`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42946495/7976758. The syntax for `extras_require` is slightly different.

Answer (score 6):

### WORKING ANSWER - 06-30-2021 @15:43 UTC

I review the *faust* repository many times and found that *aiodns*, *cython* and *ciso8601* aren't dependencies per se, but are bundles, which are installed with pip this way according to the ReadMe:

```
pip install "faust[aiodns, ciso8601, cython]"
```

I created a setup.py with your requirements.  I was able to install *faust* with the bundles *aiodns*, *ciso8601*, *cython* on a non-windows system. I don't have a windows system to test that install, but I did flip the system platform parameters, which worked.

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(

    name="faust_pip_test", # change for your package
    version="1.0.0", # change for your package
    python_requires='>=3.6',
    install_requires=["faust[aiodns, ciso8601,cython]>=1.10.1;sys_platform != 'win32'",
                  "faust[aiodns, cython]>=1.10.1;sys_platform == 'win32'",]

)
```

Here is the *faust_pip_test* package being installed with *faust* and the additional packages *aiodns*, *ciso8601* and *cython* on my MacBook.

[image]

After looking at the PipeEnv documentation, which is not intuitive it seem that you can do the following in your pipfile. Every reference I reviewed required you to specify a file path for the secondary key, which in this cause is *faust_win*. The file being called in *faust_win* is from [faust PyPi downloads](https://pypi.org/project/faust/#files).

```
[packages]
faust = {version = ">=1.10.1",extras = ["aiodns", "ciso8601", "cython"],sys_platform = "!='windows'"}
faust_win = {file = 'https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/79/f8/3fec4f5c3e5bf1ce8bb557ae507525253fa30a5cfc5984f342b931143f75/faust-1.10.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl',version = ">=1.10.1",extras = ["aiodns", "cython"],sys_platform = "=='windows'"}
```

I'm using PyCharm for my development environment. If I create a `__init__.py` in my project *faust_pipenv_test* it automatically triggers a dependencies install for my project. *Faust* [standard dependencies requirements](https://github.com/robinhood/faust/blob/master/requirements/default.txt) were installed plus the additional packages *aiodns*, *ciso8601* and *cython.*

[image]

I also received a message that the *faust_win* requirement wasn't installed, because it didn't meet this requirement `sys_platform =='win32'`.

[image]

### UPDATE 06-28-2021 @12:23 UTC

When I looked at the source code of *faust* I noted that the packages
*aiodns*, *cython* and *ciso8601* are dependencies in the *faust's* *setup.py* file.

So based on your question it seems that you don't want to install the
*faust* default dependency of *ciso8601* on a non-windows system. And based on the *extras list* it also seems that you are trying to limit other dependencies.

***Is this what you are trying to accomplish?***

The *Python Developer's Guide* states that the *"extras"* parameter is used to installed *extra dependencies*, which are in addition to the regular dependencies of a *Python* package being installed.

Reference: [PEP 426 -- Metadata for Python Software Packages 2.0](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0426/#extras-optional-dependencies)

The code below is from the PipeEnv Python package and it shows that the *"extras"* parameter is meshed with a package's core dependencies.

```
def dependencies(self):
        # type: () -> Tuple[Dict[S, PackagingRequirement], List[Union[S, PackagingRequirement]], List[S]]
        build_deps = []  # type: List[Union[S, PackagingRequirement]]
        setup_deps = []  # type: List[S]
        deps = {}  # type: Dict[S, PackagingRequirement]
        if self.setup_info:
            setup_info = self.setup_info.as_dict()
            deps.update(setup_info.get("requires", {}))
            setup_deps.extend(setup_info.get("setup_requires", []))
            build_deps.extend(setup_info.get("build_requires", []))
            if self.extras and self.setup_info.extras:
                for dep in self.extras:
                    if dep not in self.setup_info.extras:
                        continue
                    extras_list = self.setup_info.extras.get(dep, [])  # type: ignore
                    for req_instance in extras_list:  # type: ignore
                        deps[req_instance.key] = req_instance
        if self.pyproject_requires:
            build_deps.extend(list(self.pyproject_requires))
        setup_deps = list(set(setup_deps))
        build_deps = list(set(build_deps))
        return deps, setup_deps, build_deps
```

So the examples below needs testing, because it not clear in the [Advanced Usage of Pipenv](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/advanced/#specifying-basically-anything) document *if you can override the dependencies requirements from a third-party Python package.*

```
[packages]
faust = {version= ">=1.10.1", extras=["aiodns", "cython"]}
ciso8601 = {version = ">=2.1.0", sys_platform = "!= 'Windows'", index="pypi"}

or 

[packages]
faust = {version=">=1.10.1", extras=["aiodns", "ciso8601", "cython"], sys_platform= "!= 'Windows'"}
"faust_win" = {version=">=1.10.1", extras=["aiodns", "cython"], sys_platform = "== 'Windows'"}
```

### ORIGINAL POST 06-26-2021

---

Duplicate keys are not allowed in a TOML document.

For example this:

```
faust = {version=">=1.10.1", extras=["aiodns", "ciso8601", "cython"], platform_system = "!= 'Windows'"}

faust = {version=">=1.10.1", extras=["aiodns", "cython"], platform_system = "== 'Windows'"}
```

Reference the source code of [pipenv](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv)

```
# file: /pipenv/vendor/tomlkit/exceptions.py
# which is referenced from here /pipenv/vendor/tomlkit/container.py

class KeyAlreadyPresent(TOMLKitError):
    """
    An already present key was used.
    """

    def __init__(self, key):
        message = 'Key "{}" already exists.'.format(key)

        super(KeyAlreadyPresent, self).__init__(message)
```

Additionally the duplicate key issue has been discussed on [TOML](https://github.com/toml-lang/toml) Github repository.

- [Allow duplicate keys](https://github.com/toml-lang/toml/issues/697)
- [How to handle duplicate keys](https://github.com/toml-lang/toml/issues/350)

Comment: Thanks. But if I write such a key as   `faust_windows_os = {...}` how would pipenv know the real package name to look for ?  Indeed, I get the error: `Could not find a version that matches faust-windows-os[aiodns,cchardet,cython,setproctitle]>=1.10.`

Comment: This answer simply does not work. You cannot use arbitrary keys, they are used as package names.

It seems pipenv does not support this kind of thing in  a clean way
https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/3061
https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/2171