# How to install django on jython (Windows 7)

Tags: python, django, installation, jython

I have tried using the `jython setup.py install` on my computer and its not working.
And how to install `ez_setup.py` on jython or is there another way to setup django on jython

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

This tutorial [shows](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/jython/) you how to install it. Ideally everything boils down to two points:

1. First you need to get `pip`, here is a good [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6787069/1624921) on how that is done. If you don't want to read that, you can simply download `pip` from [here](https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pip/pip-1.3.1.tar.gz#md5=cbb27a191cebc58997c4da8513863153). After that, you will need to extract it, I suggest 7-zip. After that, you can go into the directory and find `setup.py`. Run `setup.py` like `jython setup.py install` -> this might be different.
2. After that, you can do something like `pip install django`, and it should work if jython is your own python interpreter. Otherwise, you are going to have to go into your jython directory, then go into a directory called `scripts`. Then run `pip.exe install django` if you're running on windows.

Please note, that my advice is from that of a Windows user, so your experience might be different, and probably a lot more pleasant.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @S.L.Barth: I did that for two reasons. First because there is a a page dedicated on the django site for doing exactly what he's asking. So it might encourage looking over the documentation in the future. Secondly, If that link goes down, then a lot of the django answers here are in jeopardy since they point to specific points in the django documentation. But, your recommendation is taken into consideration of course.

Comment: I understand your point, but this issue has been [discussed before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).  Link only answers are not good answers, and are subject to deletion (as: http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).