# How do I get easy_install to work on windows with Jython?

Tags: windows, batch-file, pip, jython, easy-install

I am trying to run easy_setup within windows 7 because I need to install pip.  After installing pip, I want to install pytz.  But after installing easy_install, I am having issues using it.

I have installed jython2.7b2 on windows 7.
I then went to download setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg and ez_setup.py. 
I put them in the same directory and then ran:

```
C:\Users\mike\Downloads>jython ez_setup.py
Processing setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
Copying setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg to c:\jython2.7b2\lib\site-packages
Adding setuptools 0.6c11 to easy-install.pth file
Installing easy_install-2.7 script to C:\jython2.7b2\bin
Installing easy_install script to C:\jython2.7b2\bin

Installed c:\jython2.7b2\lib\site-packages\setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for setuptools==0.6c11
Finished processing dependencies for setuptools==0.6c11
```

I have the tried to run the easy_install file, but of course it's not a bat file so it won't execute.

```
C:\Users\mike>easy_install pip
'easy_install' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How do I get this to work within windows? I want to get pip installed.  Is there another way to install pip?

The easy_install file contains:

```
#!C:\jython2.7b2\jython.bat
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'setuptools==0.6c11','console_scripts','easy_install'
__requires__ = 'setuptools==0.6c11'
import sys
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

sys.exit(
   load_entry_point('setuptools==0.6c11', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
)
```

Comment: What happens if you move to the C:\jython2.7b2\bin directory and run easy_install from there?

Comment: C:\jython2.7b2>easy_install pip
'easy_install' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: `pip` works only with a custom branch of [jython2.7b3](http://fwierzbicki.blogspot.ru/2014/08/jython-27-beta3-released.html).

Answer (score 0):

I tried this way with Jython 2.7.0 as in the following link by manually moving python libraries to jython.

[Jython easy_install error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22237003/jython-easy-install-error)

Refer to the answer by pitchblack408.

The answer is pretty late but may help someone.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.