# Errors importing other modules in monkeyrunner

Tags: monkeyrunner

I'm trying to import PIL with monkeyrunner

```
import re
import math
import os
from PIL import Image
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice
import commands
import sys
```

but I keep getting an error:

```
ImportError: No module named PIL
```

I know it is something with monkeyrunner because I can successfully import PIL when running a regular python script. I was reading around and maybe this had something to do with PYTHONPATH? I am not sure what I need to do to allow these other module imports with monkeyrunner.

I am running on windows.

Comment: Give **[AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient)** a try. It's 100% python so you won't have those problems.

Comment: @dtmilano so where would I put the PIL import Image or any other imports when using AndroidViewClient? After the `from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient`?

Comment: I guess it shouldn't matter

Comment: @dtmilano Just having trouble importing things. Does AndroidViewClient allow you to use the monkeyrunner classes like 'device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()` or `device.touch(253,340, 'DOWN_AND_UP')`? So I don't have to re-write everything with the ViewClient class? I am looking to just be able to use PIL and the monkeyrunner classes together. (then later expand and use ViewClient, but most of my code is written in monkeyrunner classes already)

Comment: Most of the scripts will run with no or small changes.

Answer (score 1):

You should install PIL for Python 2.5 under '/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/'. Because MonkeyRunner uses Jython 2.5, based on Python 2.5.

Then add the path of PIL to Jython's path.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/your-PIL')
```

See [How I install various Python libraries in Jython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787015/how-can-i-install-various-python-libraries-in-jython) for details.