# How do I install Robot framework and selenium 2 library with Jython?

Tags: selenium, jython, robotframework

I searched a lot regarding this. Still I didn't get any definite answer for this. Someone Please explain me on how to do this. Please mention the compatible versions also.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/6787015/7432 -- robot and selenium2library are python packages and the referenced question asks how to install python packages with jython.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Selenium 2 java robot framework.

Just add the following dependency to the pom file (if you use maven)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.markusbernhardt</groupId>
        <artifactId>robotframework-selenium2library-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

If you don't use maven, just download the jar from
https://github.com/MarkusBernhardt/robotframework-selenium2library-java

(You can find a link there to the jar with the dependencies in it)

This is compatible with all jython versions (since it's java based)