# trap exceptions comprehensively in Jython

Tags: exception, jython, throwable

This is my attempt so far to trap all exceptions in Jython code.  The most difficult thing, I find, is trapping exceptions when you override a method from a Java class: with the "vigil" decorator below (which also tests whether the EDT/Event Despatch Thread status is correct) you can find out the first line where the code is thrown... so you can identify the method itself.  But not the line.

Furthermore, tracing stack frames back through Python and Java stacks is completely beyond me.  Obviously there seem to be these layers and layers of "proxy" classes, a no doubt inevitable part of Jython mechanics.  It'd be great if someone much cleverer than me were to take an interest in this question!

NB this is an example of how to use the "vigil" decorator:

```
    class ColumnCellRenderer( javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer ):
        @vigil( True ) # means a check is done that the thread is the EDT, as well as intercepting Python Exceptions and Java Throwables...
        def getTableCellRendererComponent( self, table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column):
            super_comp = self.super__getTableCellRendererComponent( table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column)
            super_comp.foreground = java.awt.Color.black
            super_comp.font = main_frame_self.m_plain_font
            ...
```

... and these are three functions I use in an attempt to trap stuff...

```
def custom_hook(type_of_e, e, tb ):
    """
Method to catch Python-style BaseExceptions, using the command sys.excepthook = custom_hook.
The first thing this method needs to do in Jython is to determine whether this is a Java 
java.lang.Throwable or not.  If it is this JThrowable
must be handled by the code which caters for B{uncaught Java Throwables}.        
    """
    try:

        if 'tb' not in locals():
            tb = None
        logger.error("Python custom_hook called...\ntype of e: %s\ne: %s\ntb: %s" % ( unicode( type_of_e ), unicode( e ), 
                                                                                    unicode( tb ) ))
        msg = ''.join( traceback.format_exception(type_of_e, e, tb ))
        logger.error( "traceback:\n" + msg )
    except BaseException, e:
        logger.error( "exception in Python custom_hook!:\n%s" % e )
        raise e
sys.excepthook = custom_hook

class JavaUncaughtExceptHandler( java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler ):
    """
java.lang.Class to catch any Java Throwables thrown by the app.        
    """
    def uncaughtException( self, thread, throwable ):
        try:
            '''
NB getting the Java stack trace like this seems to produce a very different trace 
from throwable.printStackTrace()... why?             
            '''
            # we want a single log message
            exception_msg = "\n*** uncaught Java Exception being logged in %s:\n" % __file__
            baos = java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream()
            ps = java.io.PrintStream(baos)
            throwable.printStackTrace( ps )
            # remove multiple lines from Java stack trace message
            java_stack_trace_lines = unicode( baos.toString( "ISO-8859-1" )).splitlines()
            java_stack_trace_lines = filter( None, java_stack_trace_lines  )
            normalised_java_stack_trace = '\n'.join( java_stack_trace_lines )
            exception_msg += normalised_java_stack_trace + '\n'
            python_traceback_string = traceback.format_exc()
            exception_msg += "Python traceback:\n%s" % python_traceback_string
            logger.error( exception_msg )
        except (BaseException, java.lang.Throwable ), e:
            logger.error( "*** exception in Java exception handler:\ntype %s\n%s" % ( type( e ), unicode( e ) ) )
            raise e
        # NB printStackTrace causes the custom_hook to be invoked... (but doesn't print anything)
java.lang.Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler( JavaUncaughtExceptHandler()  )


def vigil( *args ):
    """
Decorator with two functions.  
1. to check that a method is being run in the EDT or a non-EDT thread; 
2. to catch any Java Throwables which otherwise would not be properly caught and documented: in particular, 
with normal Java error-trapping in Jython it seems impossible to determine the line number at which an 
Exception was thrown.  This at least records the line at which a Java java.lang.Throwable
was thrown.
    """
    if len( args ) != 1:
        raise Exception( "vigil: wrong number of args (should be 1, value: None/True/False): %s" % str( args ))
    req_edt = args[ 0 ]
    if req_edt and type( req_edt ) is not bool:
        raise Exception( "vigil: edt_status is wrong type: %s, type %s" % ( req_edt, type( req_edt )) )
    def real_decorator( function ):
        if not hasattr( function, '__call__' ):
            raise Exception( "vigil: function %s does not have __call__ attr, type %s" 
                % ( function, type( function )) )

        # NB info about decorator location can't be got when wrapper called, so record it at this point
        penultimate_frame = traceback.extract_stack()[ -2 ] 
        decorator_file = penultimate_frame[ 0 ]    
        decorator_line_no = penultimate_frame[ 1 ]    
        def wrapper( *args, **kvargs ):
            try:
                # TODO is it possible to get the Python and/or Java stack trace at this point?
                if req_edt and javax.swing.SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread() != req_edt:
                    logger.error( "*** vigil: wrong EDT value, should be %s\nfile %s, line no %s, function: %s\n" % 
        ( "EDT" if req_edt else "non-EDT", decorator_file, decorator_line_no, function ))
                return function( *args, **kvargs )
            except ( BaseException, java.lang.Throwable ), e:
                ''' NB All sorts of problems if a vigil-protected function throws an exception:
1) just raising e means you get a very short stack trace...
2) if you list the stack trace elements here you get a line (seemingly inside the function where the 
exception occurred) but often the wrong line!
3) Python/Java stack frames: how the hell does it all work???
4) want a single error message to be logged                
                ''' 
                msg = "*** exception %s caught by vigil in file %s\nin function starting line %d" % ( e, decorator_file, decorator_line_no )
                logger.error( msg )
                frame = inspect.currentframe()
                # the following doesn't seem to work... why not?
                python_stack_trace = traceback.format_stack(frame)
                python_stack_string = "Python stack trace:\n"
                for el in python_stack_trace[ : -1 ]:
                    python_stack_string += el
                logger.error( python_stack_string )
                if isinstance( e, java.lang.Throwable ):
                    # NB problems with this stack trace: although it appears to show the 
                    # correct Java calling pathway, it seems that the line number of every file and method 
                    # is always shown as being the last line, wherever the exception was actually raised.
                    # Possibly try and get hold of the actual Pyxxx objects ... (?)
                    java_stack_trace = e.stackTrace
                    java_stack_string = "Java stack trace:\n"
                    for el in java_stack_trace:
                        java_stack_string += "  %s\n" % unicode( el )
                    logger.error( java_stack_string )
                    raise e
        return wrapper
    return real_decorator
```

PS it is of course possible to top-and-tail every overridden Java method with try ... except... but where's the fun in that?  Seriously, even doing that I'm unable to find the line at which the exception is thrown...

Comment: It might give better result to use `except:` (i.e. without specifying type) and accessing the exception through `sys.exc_info()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jim Baker's answer is interesting... but what I wanted is sthg comprehensive which documents the maximum possible amount of stack trace info when an exception of any kind is raised.  CPython not being multi-thread, its stack trace doesn't have to cope with Runnables.  I'm not enough of a Jython/Python expert to know whether you can always get the whole stack in "pure Python" code (i.e. no use of Java classes).

But one of the things I wanted to get was the activity which had led up to the running of a Runnable in Jython.  And the activity which had led up to the Runnable having run that Runnable, etc., right back to the very first thread.  My solution below, taking inspiration from Jim's answer but also from doublep's comment, creates a new Jython class, TraceableRunnable, which will store the list of stack traces on creation.

When an exception, either Java or Python style, is raised, this logs everything right back to the start of the run (if you systematically use TraceableRunnable instead of Runnable).

Each run() code of a TraceableRunner subclass also has to do this call at some point:

```
self.record_thread()
```

... hopefully this is not too irksome an imposition...

(NB in a truly "grown up" implementation you'd want to check that this call had been made... I'm sure that this could be done by some suitably sophisticated Pythonic technique, failing which by unit testing or something.  Also you might want to require a call at the very end of the run() code to delete this dictionary entry...)

This is the catching and logging code:

```
class TraceableRunnable( java.lang.Runnable ):
    thread_to_tr_dic = {}
    def __init__( self  ):
        # no need to call super's __init__: Runnable is a Java *interface*
        caller_thread = java.lang.Thread.currentThread()
        self.frame_stack_list = []
        if hasattr( caller_thread, 'frame_stack_list' ):
            self.frame_stack_list = copy.deepcopy( caller_thread.frame_stack_list )
        self.frame_stack_list.append( traceback.extract_stack() )

    def record_thread( self ):
        TraceableRunnable.thread_to_tr_dic[ java.lang.Thread.currentThread() ] = self

class EDTException( Exception ):
    pass     

def vigil( *args ):
    """
Decorator with two functions.  
1. to check that a method is being run in the EDT or a non-EDT thread 
2. to catch any exceptions
    """
    if len( args ) != 1:
        raise Exception( "vigil: wrong number of args (should be 1, value: None/True/False): %s" % str( args ))
    req_edt = args[ 0 ]
    if req_edt and type( req_edt ) is not bool:
        raise Exception( "vigil: edt_status is wrong type: %s, type %s" % ( req_edt, type( req_edt )) )


    def process_exception( exc, python = True ):
        tb_obj = sys.exc_info()[ 2 ]
        msg = "Exception thrown message %s\nfamily %s, type: %s\n" % ( str( exc ), "Python" if python else "Java", type( exc ))
        msg += "traceback object part:\n"    
        ex_tb = traceback.extract_tb( tb_obj )
        # first is frame in vigil
        ex_tb = ex_tb[ 1 : ]
        if not ex_tb:
            msg += "  none\n"
        else:
            tb_strings = traceback.format_list( ex_tb )
            for tb_string in tb_strings:
                msg += tb_string

        curr_thread = java.lang.Thread.currentThread()
        if curr_thread in TraceableRunnable.thread_to_tr_dic:
            runnable = TraceableRunnable.thread_to_tr_dic[ curr_thread ]
            # duck-typing, obviously... although redundant test, as only TraceableRunnables should be in the dictionary...
            if hasattr( runnable, 'frame_stack_list' ):
                msg += "\nOLDER STACKS:\n" 
                for frame_stack in runnable.frame_stack_list:
                    msg += "\nframe stack id: %d\n" % id( frame_stack )
                    frame_stack = frame_stack[  : -1 ]
                    if not frame_stack:
                        msg += "  no frames\n"
                    else:
                        # most recent call first: reverse array...
                        stack_strings = traceback.format_list( reversed( frame_stack ))
                        for stack_string in stack_strings:
                            msg += stack_string
        logger.error( msg )


    def real_decorator( function ):
        if not hasattr( function, '__call__' ):
            raise Exception( "vigil: function %s does not have __call__ attr, type %s" 
                % ( function, type( function )) )
        # NB info about decorator location can't be got when wrapper called, so record it at this point
        penultimate_frame = traceback.extract_stack()[ -2 ] 
        decorator_file = penultimate_frame[ 0 ]    
        decorator_line_no = penultimate_frame[ 1 ]    
        def wrapper( *args, **kvargs ):
            try:
                if req_edt is not None and javax.swing.SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread() != req_edt:
                    msg = \
"vigil: wrong EDT value, should be %s\nfile %s\nline no %s, function: %s" % \
( "EDT" if req_edt else "non-EDT", decorator_file, decorator_line_no, function ) 
                    raise EDTException( msg )
                return function( *args, **kvargs )
            except BaseException, e:
                # we cannot know how calling code will want to deal with an EDTException 
                if type( e ) is EDTException:
                    raise e
                process_exception( e )
            except java.lang.Throwable, t:
                process_exception( t, False )
        return wrapper
    return real_decorator
```

Would welcome improvements from proper programmers...!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of a decorator used in the socket module in Jython to map Java exceptions to Python exceptions. I didn't read your `vigil` decorator too closely since it's doing a lot of work, but I'm putting it here in case it might help:

```
def raises_java_exception(method_or_function):
    """Maps java socket exceptions to the equivalent python exception.
    Also sets _last_error on socket objects so as to support SO_ERROR.
    """

    @wraps(method_or_function)
    def handle_exception(*args, **kwargs):
        is_socket = len(args) > 0 and isinstance(args[0], _realsocket)
        try:
            try:
                return method_or_function(*args, **kwargs)
            except java.lang.Exception, jlx:
                raise _map_exception(jlx)
        except error, e:
            if is_socket:
                args[0]._last_error = e[0]
            raise
        else:
            if is_socket:
                args[0]._last_error = 0
    return handle_exception
```

Mostly what we are seeing here is that we are dispatching on whether it is a Java exception (`java.lang.Exception`) or not. I suppose this could be generalized to `java.lang.Throwable`, although it's unclear what can be done in the case of `java.lang.Error` in any event. Certainly nothing corresponding to socket errors!

The above decorator in turn uses the `_map_exception` function to unwrap the Java exception. It's quite application specific here as you can see:

```
def _map_exception(java_exception):
    if isinstance(java_exception, NettyChannelException):
        java_exception = java_exception.cause  # unwrap
    if isinstance(java_exception, SSLException) or isinstance(java_exception, CertificateException):
        cause = java_exception.cause
        if cause:
            msg = "%s (%s)" % (java_exception.message, cause)
        else:
            msg = java_exception.message
        py_exception = SSLError(SSL_ERROR_SSL, msg)
    else:
        mapped_exception = _exception_map.get(java_exception.__class__)
        if mapped_exception:
            py_exception = mapped_exception(java_exception)
        else:
            py_exception = error(-1, 'Unmapped exception: %s' % java_exception)
    py_exception.java_exception = java_exception
    return _add_exception_attrs(py_exception)
```

There is some clunkiness in the code, and I'm sure room for improvement, but overall it certainly makes any decorated code much easier to follow. Example:

```
@raises_java_exception
def gethostname():
    return str(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName())
```