# How to install Jython on windows 7?

Tags: java, python, windows-7, jython

I have downloaded the latest version from jython.org and I installed the file.. I also set the PATH variable to its bin folder after installation. But when I am executing in command prompt by writing jython, it is giving error.[image]

Comment: Could you please provide 1) what you have installed (installer or standalone) 2) your PATH setting.

Comment: I downloaded the installer from here, not stand alone.. http://www.jython.org/downloads.html

Comment: Also Path is set to C:\jython2.7.0\bin

Comment: Well, the PATH should have a bunch more entries, it might be what it's looking for.

Comment: Like what kind of more entries? I am very new here. Pls help

Comment: Like for instance `%SystemRoot%\system32`, it seems like you just overwrote the `PATH` completely. The idea is to _add_ the bin folder to the end of it. Any ways, it should actually be fine like that too.

Comment: I can not reproduce the problem myself. I did find someone who had the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30410385/jython-exe-2-7-0-final-release-failed-execution-on-my-windows-os

Comment: It worked.. I actually deleted java from path and that is why it was throwing back those error..
Thank you