# Got errors when using jython ez_setup.py in python

Tags: jython

New to Jython. 

I am this following [How can I install various Python libraries in Jython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787015/how-can-i-install-various-python-libraries-in-jython) to use $ jython ez_setup.py, but ends with this error

```
Traceback (innermost last):
File "ez_setup.py", line 278, in ?
File "ez_setup.py", line 210, in main
File "ez_setup.py", line 139, in download_setuptools
ImportError: no module named distutils
```

I download ez_setup.py from here http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py. I have installed jython correct under the guidance from here http://www.jython.org/archive/22/installation.html

Thank you guys in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `distutils` is not available in your version of Jython.  From the link you provided, it looks like you are using Jython2.2, and when I start Jython2.2.1 and try to import `distutils`, I also get an `ImportError`:

```
Jython 2.2.1 on java1.7.0_79
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import distutils
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in ?
ImportError: no module named distutils
>>>
```

On a more recent version of Jython, the `distutils` module imports successfully:

```
Jython 2.7b2 (default:a5bc0032cf79+, Apr 22 2014, 21:20:17) 
[Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (Oracle Corporation)] on java1.8.0_60
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import distutils
>>>
```

Is there a reason you must such an old version of Jython?

Comment: Thx! The older version is the problem. I try jython 2.5.2 and it works. Yours 2.7b2 is even better!