# How do I track Jython's Python install in runtime? (sys.executable isn't enough)

Tags: jython

I'm using a Python API for a Java application, which I'll call `app_x`.

Being a Java application, it uses Jython which I'm only getting to know because of it.

So I found out about its version, executable and path with `sys` module to be:

```
### System Version: 2.7.1 (v2.7.1:dd7e191d4c90, Nov 14 2017, 14:18:32) 
[OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Oracle Corporation)]
### System Exec: /home/myself/.app_x/python/bin/jython
### System Path:
/home/myself/.app_x/python, /home/myself/.app_x/python/Lib,  
  /opt/App_X/lib/mdpython.jar/Lib, __classpath__, __pyclasspath__/
Finished running normally at Thu Sep 24 20:10:31 CDT 2020
```

I'd like to use libraries that aren't installed there;  for which I found other posts recommending to use `easy_install` for them.

However, as I look into the executable and the paths related to it, I find that
`/home/myself/.app_x/python` has no `.../bin` in it -only `.../cache`-; and the only other
non-empty path location is `/opt/App-X/lib/mdpython.jar/Lib` which isn't for Python packages.

Thus... I don't know where to install my packages.

Would anyone know how to find such location?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using [Jython Standalone](https://www.jython.org/download)? If so, this looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/43699968/407651.

Comment: Thanks.  I wasn't previously aware of the standalone, but since it's used for another application it does seem to be the case.  I've tried some of the solutions suggested, but haven't still gotten to install `pandas` or at least `numpy`.  It seems the former isn't allowed, but maybe the latter is. 
Are you aware if `numpy` is based on C?

Comment: NumPy and Pandas do not work with Jython. See https://scipy.org/scipylib/faq.html#does-numpy-scipy-work-with-jython-or-c-net and https://stackoverflow.com/q/36213908/407651