# from bs4 import BeautifulSoup ImportError: No module named bs4 when calling a python method from java by using jython

Tags: java, python, python-3.x, jython

I am using Jyhton to call my Python methods through the Java methods. Python methods contains `BeautifulSoup to import bs4`. These methods are working fine in Python. But when I call these methods from Java, the error **ImportError: No module named bs4** occurred. I am using `Python 3.6` and `Jython 2.7`. Also I have set the properties as the directory which contains my Python scripts for the Jython Interpreter.

```
Directory path : /home/user/devs/python-devs
```

python-dev directory contains all my python scripts which are organized into several sub directories.

Comment: Could you put your path? otherwise I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787015/how-can-i-install-various-python-libraries-in-jython) might be your problem

Comment: @Mntfr question is edited with the directory path.

Comment: @Mntfr I tried the provided link. But did not solve my question.