# JMeter with Python Selenium

Tags: selenium, jmeter, jython

I was checking how i can use existing selenium scripts written in python for JMeter. There are suggestions to use Jython. i have installed jython by putting jython jar file in lib.
Using JSR223 Sampler, when I tried to give the existing selenium script file it is giving me below error while hitting run

```
> Data type ("text"|"bin"|""):text Response code:500 Response
> message:javax.script.ScriptException: ImportError: No module named  selenium in <script> at line number 1
```

Do i need to use third party tool to convert existing scripts to JMX file?

My second question is :- I checked the documentation and found that it works on python2.7 version. Is that really correct? How come it is not updated to python3

Answer (score 1):

> No module named  selenium in

It looks like you didn't install [selenium module](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/), you need to install it in order to be able to use it like:

```
 jython -m pip install selenium
```

More information: [How can I install various Python libraries in Jython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787015/how-can-i-install-various-python-libraries-in-jython)

However if you want to use existing Python UI tests for performance testing it's better to consider converting them to JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers, as each thread (virtual user) needs to run a real browser and a real browser needs 1 CPU core and a couple of gigabytes of RAM so you can simulate thousands of users on HTTP protocol level using the hardware allowing to launch several browsers only.

See [How to Convert Selenium Scripts into the JMX Converter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-convert-selenium-scripts-jmx-converter) article for more details.