# How to deal with Jython and moviepy Error?

Tags: python, java, spring, jython-2.7

I need to help about the Spring project for Java in IntelliJ.
Im gonna use Jython and moviepy in python code. I guess the error caused by these.
Actually I found numpy was not applied in Jython. But I have no idea about solved this PROBLEMS.
Please tell me how can I do!

Error Code

```
File "src/main/java/com/woojoofolio/project/springboot/jython/VideoEditor.py", line 4, in <module>
    from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, concatenate_videoclips
  File "C:\study\Lib\site-packages\moviepy\editor.py", line 24, in <module>
    import imageio
  File "C:\study\Lib\site-packages\imageio\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from .core import FormatManager, RETURN_BYTES
  File "C:\study\Lib\site-packages\imageio\core\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .util import Image, Array, Dict, asarray, image_as_uint, urlopen
  File "C:\study\Lib\site-packages\imageio\core\util.py", line 10, in <module>
    import numpy as np
SyntaxError: ("no viable alternative at input 'from'", ('C:\\study\\Lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\__init__.py', 130, 31, '        raise ImportError(msg) from e\n'))
] with root cause

org.python.core.PySyntaxError: SyntaxError: no viable alternative at input 'from' (__init__.py, line 130)
    at org.python.core.ParserFacade.fixParseError(ParserFacade.java:95) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.ParserFacade.parse(ParserFacade.java:190) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.imp.compileSource(imp.java:542) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.imp.createFromSource(imp.java:575) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.imp.loadFromSource(imp.java:944) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.imp.find_module(imp.java:769) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.imp.import_next(imp.java:1158) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.imp.import_first(imp.java:1219) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.imp.import_module_level(imp.java:1361) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.imp.importName(imp.java:1528) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.ImportFunction.__call__(__builtin__.java:1285) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:433) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.__builtin__.__import__(__builtin__.java:1232) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.imp.importOneAs(imp.java:1564) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at imageio.core.util$py.f$0(C:/study/Lib/site-packages/imageio/core/util.py:542) ~[na:na]
    at imageio.core.util$py.call_function(C:/study/Lib/site-packages/imageio/core/util.py) ~[na:na]
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:173) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.PyCode.call(PyCode.java:18) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.imp.createFromCode(imp.java:630) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.imp.createFromPyClass(imp.java:312) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.imp.createFromPyClass(imp.java:255) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.imp.loadFromSource(imp.java:929) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.imp.find_module(imp.java:769) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.PyModule.findSubModule(PyModule.java:140) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.PyModule.impAttr(PyModule.java:107) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.imp.import_next(imp.java:1161) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.imp.import_module_level(imp.java:1350) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.imp.importName(imp.java:1528) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.ImportFunction.__call__(__builtin__.java:1285) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:433) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.__builtin__.__import__(__builtin__.java:1232) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.imp.importFromAs(imp.java:1620) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.imp.importFrom(imp.java:1595) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at imageio.core$py.f$0(C:/study/Lib/site-packages/imageio/core/__init__.py:16) ~[na:na]
    at imageio.core$py.call_function(C:/study/Lib/site-packages/imageio/core/__init__.py) ~[na:na]
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:173) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.PyCode.call(PyCode.java:18) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.imp.createFromCode(imp.java:630) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.imp.createFromPyClass(imp.java:312) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.imp.createFromPyClass(imp.java:255) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.imp.loadFromSource(imp.java:929) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.imp.find_module(imp.java:769) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.PyModule.findSubModule(PyModule.java:140) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.PyModule.impAttr(PyModule.java:107) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.imp.import_next(imp.java:1161) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.imp.import_module_level(imp.java:1350) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.imp.importName(imp.java:1528) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.ImportFunction.__call__(__builtin__.java:1285) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:433) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.__builtin__.__import__(__builtin__.java:1232) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.imp.importFromAs(imp.java:1620) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.imp.importFrom(imp.java:1595) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at imageio$py.f$0(C:/study/Lib/site-packages/imageio/__init__.py:100) ~[na:na]
    at imageio$py.call_function(C:/study/Lib/site-packages/imageio/__init__.py) ~[na:na]
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:173) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.PyCode.call(PyCode.java:18) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.imp.createFromCode(imp.java:630) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.imp.createFromPyClass(imp.java:312) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.imp.createFromPyClass(imp.java:255) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.imp.loadFromSource(imp.java:929) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.imp.find_module(imp.java:769) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.imp.import_next(imp.java:1158) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.imp.import_first(imp.java:1219) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.imp.import_module_level(imp.java:1361) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.imp.importName(imp.java:1528) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.ImportFunction.__call__(__builtin__.java:1285) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:433) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.__builtin__.__import__(__builtin__.java:1232) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.imp.importOne(imp.java:1547) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at moviepy.editor$py.f$0(C:/study/Lib/site-packages/moviepy/editor.py:131) ~[na:na]
    at moviepy.editor$py.call_function(C:/study/Lib/site-packages/moviepy/editor.py) ~[na:na]
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:173) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.PyCode.call(PyCode.java:18) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.imp.createFromCode(imp.java:630) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.imp.createFromPyClass(imp.java:312) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.imp.createFromPyClass(imp.java:255) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.imp.loadFromSource(imp.java:929) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.imp.find_module(imp.java:769) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.PyModule.findSubModule(PyModule.java:140) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.PyModule.impAttr(PyModule.java:107) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.imp.import_next(imp.java:1161) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.imp.import_logic(imp.java:1278) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.imp.import_module_level(imp.java:1369) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.imp.importName(imp.java:1528) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.ImportFunction.__call__(__builtin__.java:1285) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:433) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.__builtin__.__import__(__builtin__.java:1232) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.imp.importFromAs(imp.java:1620) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.imp.importFrom(imp.java:1595) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.pycode._pyx0.f$0(src/main/java/com/woojoofolio/project/springboot/jython/VideoEditor.py:9) ~[na:na]
    at org.python.pycode._pyx0.call_function(src/main/java/com/woojoofolio/project/springboot/jython/VideoEditor.py) ~[na:na]
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:173) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.PyCode.call(PyCode.java:18) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.Py.runCode(Py.java:1687) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.core.__builtin__.execfile_flags(__builtin__.java:535) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.execfile(PythonInterpreter.java:287) ~[jython.jar:2.7.2]
    at com.woojoofolio.project.springboot.jython.JythonTest.getTest(JythonTest.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.doFilterInternal(DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.java:52) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:206) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.java:160) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:151) ~[spring-session-core-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:86) ~[spring-session-core-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

Source code in Java

```
private static PythonInterpreter intPre;
public String getTest() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
 intPre = new PythonInterpreter();
 intPre.execfile("src/main/java/com/woojoofolio/project/springboot/jython/VideoEditor.py");
 PyFunction pyFunction = (PyFunction) intPre.get("video_editor", PyFunction.class);
 
 String a = "01.mp4";
 PyObject pyObject = pyFunction.__call__(new PyString(a));
 System.out.println(pyObject.toString());

 return pyObject.toString();
}
```

Source cide in Python

```
import sys

sys.path.append('C:\study\Lib\site-packages')
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, concatenate_videoclips

import math


def video_editor(file):
    video_path = file

    threshold = 0.2
    window_size = 0.5
    video = VideoFileClip(video_path)
    n_windows = math.floor(video.audio.end / window_size)

    keep_clips = []

    is_prev_silence = True
    start_time = 0
    end_time = 0

    for i in range(n_windows):
        s = video.audio.subclip(i * window_size, (i + 1) * window_size)

        if s.max_volume() >= threshold:
            if is_prev_silence:
                start_time = i * window_size

            is_prev_silence = False

        else:
            if not is_prev_silence:
                end_time = i * window_size
                keep_clips.append(video.subclip(start_time, end_time))
                print({start_time} - {end_time})

            is_prev_silence = True

    edited_video = concatenate_videoclips(keep_clips)

    edited_video.write_videofile(
        'C:/own_project/woojoofolio/src/main/java/com/woojoofolio/project/springboot/jython/out.mp4',
        audio_codec='aac',
        threads=16
    )

    video.close()
    edited_video.close()

    return "success"
```

I expected moviepy library is worked.but I didn`t.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install various Python libraries in Jython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787015/how-can-i-install-various-python-libraries-in-jython)